# Remote Data won't show on tableView

Tags: swift, tableview, remote-access

I'm clueless as to what is wrong. My console doesn't give me any errors, my code seems fine but nothing is showing up. Could someone check my code, see why it doesn't want to work? My tableView is connected with its delegates and source. Not sure what is the problem.

Here is my code:

```
private let cellIdentifier = "cell"
private let apiURL = "api link"


class TableView: UITableViewController {


//TableView Outlet
@IBOutlet weak var LegTableView: UITableView!


//API Array
var legislatorArray = [congressClass]()


func getLegislators (fromSession session: NSURLSession) {

    //Calling url
    if let jsonData = NSURL(string: apiURL) {

        // Requesting url
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(jsonData) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            //Check for errors
            if let error = error {print(error)
            } else {
                if let http = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                    if http.statusCode == 200 {

                        //Getting data
                        if let data = data {

                            do {

                                let legislatorData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers)

                                //Get API data
                                if let getData = legislatorData as? [NSObject:AnyObject],
                                    findObject = getData["results"] as? [AnyObject]{

                                    //Return data
                                    for cellFound in findObject{

                                        if let nextCell = cellFound["results"] as? [NSObject:AnyObject],

                                            name = nextCell["first_name"] as? String,
                                            lastName = nextCell["last_name"] as? String,
                                            title = nextCell["title"] as? String,
                                            partyRep = nextCell["party"] as? String,
                                            position = nextCell ["position"] as? String,
                                            id = nextCell ["bioguide_id"] as? String

                                        {

                                            //Add data to array
                                            let addData = congressClass(name: name, lastName: lastName, title: title, party: partyRep, position: position, bioID: id)
                                            self.legislatorArray.append(addData)
                                        }
                                    }//end cellFound

                                    //Adding data to table
                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                                //end do
                            catch {print(error)}

                        }//end data

                    }//end statusCode

                }//end http

            }//else

        }//end task

        //Run code
        task.resume()

    }//end jsonData


}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
    getLegislators(fromSession: urlSession)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

   //TableView Rows
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return legislatorArray.count
    //return 5
}

//Cell Configuration
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTableView

    cell.lesName?.text = legislatorArray[indexPath.row].name + " " + legislatorArray[indexPath.row].lastName
    cell.lesTitle?.text = legislatorArray[indexPath.row].title
    cell.lesParty?.text = legislatorArray[indexPath.row].party

    //These tests worked fine.. the tableView is working. But the data doesn't seem to pass.
    //cell.lesName.text = "Name" + " " + "lastName"
    //cell.lesTitle.text = "Title goes here"
    //cell.lesParty.text = "D"

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: 'if let nextCell = cellFound["results"] as? [NSObject:AnyObject]' won't show because there is no "results" for every legislator and nextCell ["position"] doesn't exist either

Answer (score 2):

You're not reloading the tableView

The problem is in this piece of code

```
                                //-----------------------------

                                //New empty array for api data
                                var indexPath:[NSIndexPath] = []

                                //Adding data to new array
                                for i in 0..<self.legislatorArray.count{
                                    let secondIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
                                    indexPath.append(secondIndexPath)
                                }

                                //Adding data to table
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                                    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPath, withRowAnimation: .Left)
                                }
```

You don't need any of that. You can just reload the tableView as follows:

```
                            //Adding data to table
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                                //You only need to reload it and that should do the trick
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
```

I know you said your tableView is connected to the delegate and dataSource but it's not showing in your code.

You conformed the ViewController to the correct protocols but you need something like this in your viewDidLoad.

```
self.tableView.deletage = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
//I don't know if this was a typo but in your cellForRowAtIndexPath you are using CellTableView
let nibName = UINib(nibName: "CellTableView", bundle:nil)
self.tableView.registerNib(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
```

I created an example of a better design for your implementation
This is for the WebService and your Custom Class
https://github.com/phantomon/Stackoverflow/blob/master/SO1/MyTableView/MyTableView/Models/WebServiceManager.swift

This is for the ViewController with your tableView
https://github.com/phantomon/Stackoverflow/blob/master/SO1/MyTableView/MyTableView/ViewController.swift

You just need to modify the UITableViewCell with your custom one.
And of course review your custom class data.

Comment: CellTableView is my cell's custom view... and I tried all these here and still nothing :/

Comment: Can you show me the updated version? maybe with pastebin or updating the question?

Comment: yeah sure... i changed alot of things, but nothing is working.

Comment: I made a repository for you https://github.com/phantomon/Stackoverflow/tree/master/SO1/MyTableView

Comment: Thank you so much for the git, I fix it, everything shows now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121797/discussion-between-edder-nunez-and-nadia-g).